# Extremly slow STS startup, loading org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui

Tags: spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

when I start my STS (3.5.1.RELEASE) it takes about 5 Minutes to startup.
On the splashscreen I can see "loading org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui"

I've allready disabled the Option "Show Dasboad on Startup".

Does anyone has an idea?

Even my colleagues have the same problem.

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: I am seeing the same issue on 3.6.0. I am behind a (pretty lousy) proxy, using the Active Provider as "Native" to pick up my system's proxy settings. Disabling the dashboard doesn't seem to help, and neither does removing all the feeds.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in STS up to version 3.6.0. This will be fixed in 3.6.1. See https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3861

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is related to a network issue, I experienced a similar behavior in situations where my network access was problematic. Are you behind a firewall and/or proxy? And did you configure that in the Eclipse network preferences?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is with loading org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui,simply delete(take backup before delete) \stsWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui folder.

If this doesn't resolve your isue then delete sts-3.8.1.RELEASE\plugins\org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui_3.8.1-RELEASE.jar.

It works for me.

PS note : It will not load dashboard while loading workspace.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what worked for me.
When STS got stuck, opened IE, Tools --> Internet Options --> Connections --> LAN settings --> unchecked all proxy settings.
Then killed STS session from *Task Manager* and opened it again. 
And this time it did not get stuck.
 Then I went back into IE to fix the proxy settings.